# Why is this character's hammer rounded?

Tags: game-of-thrones, weapon

> Gendry

made a comeback in last night's (S7E5) episode, and with him came his new war-hammer. We notice that the hammer is rounded, but wouldn't it be stronger/better if the end came to a point?

I would think that it would be easier to pierce armor that way, since a sharp point at the end of the hammer provides more pressure, which i assume is necessary to penetrate thick armor?

Comment: I don't think we have an in-universe reason. I'd recommend rephrasing this question and taking it to another SE asking "Is a rounding war-hammer better than a pointed one?" since at that point it becauses a science based question. Or maybehistory.se to find out what they used in the past.

Comment: I think only one side was rounded....

Comment: Check out Lindybeige's article about round versus pointed axes at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fpYIPlVx4Rs. TL;DL, a rounded surface is less likely to bounce off of curved armor.

Comment: I agree with @amflare, I think this is more of a physics question; but here are some things to consider: A rounded hammer is easier to use to make continuous swings, while hammer that ends in a point (which is really a chisel or a pick and not a hammer) is more likely to get stuck in the thing you're sticking, making it harder to make continuous swings since you'll have to wrench it out of a target after each swing.

Comment: Although funny to point out, we closed this one as off-topic yet the one about gates was left open.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Only one side of Gendry's war-hammer was rounded. The other side did indeed have a point/spike. This is totally consistent  with [real-life hammers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_hammer) used in combat.

[image: gendry's hammer]

> War hammers were developed as a consequence of the prevalence of surface-hardened steel surfacing of wrought iron armors of the late medieval battlefields during the fourteenth and fifteenth centuries. The surface of armors had become as hard as the edge of a blade, so blades tended to ricochet. Swords and battleaxes were likely to give only glancing blows, losing much of their impact, especially on the high curvature of helmets. **A war hammer could deliver the full force of a blow to the target.**
>
> War hammers, especially when mounted on a pole, could damage without penetrating armor. **In particular, they transmitted their impact through even the thickest helmets and caused concussions.** Later war hammers often had a spike on one side of the head, making them more versatile weapons.